Pandas Filtering Syntax
I'm trying to find mean price for specific stock.

How do get mean price of APPL?
I'm trying:
price_data= data['stock'=='AAPL','price']

I'm still trying to get it, but I'm getting an error:



header 1
header 2




cell 1
cell 2


cell 3
cell 4




https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO! Please edit your post so as to share all code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images. That includes the initial dataframe. To share dataframes: copy-paste the output of print(data.head()).

Use price_data= data.loc['stock'=='AAPL','price'].mean()

data.groupby('stock')['price'].mean()

